# How to Clear Hashtag from URL on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, anchor, hashtag

If I send someone a link `http://example.com/#about` how can I go about clearing that hashtag and text from the URL on page load `http://example.com`.

I've been building lightboxes that utilize the CSS `:target` attribute. I would like it so if someone sends or clicks a link with the hashtag and text appended to the URL that the page essentially ignores it or clears it from the URL on load.

I thought this would be a pretty common issue with a simple answer but haven't run across anything in my research. I'm open to answers that include JavaScript & jQuery.

Comment: `parent.location.hash='' ;` This should remove the hash

Comment: alert(window.location.href.split('#')[0]);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind the hashtag being present but empty, you can use:

```
document.location.hash = '';
```

Which will change `http://example.com/#about` to `http://example.com/#` without reloading the page, also has higher backwards compatibility than `history.pushState`.

You can use it after making sure the popup or whatever is loaded properly, just call this line as it is and it'll work.

Comment: What's the quickest way to execute this code?

Right now I'm using this in the header, but would love for it to execute quicker.

`window.ready = function() { parent.location.hash='' ;  };`

Comment: I wouldn't rely on anything quicker than waiting for the document to properly load. So I'd execute it either right after handling the lightbox or using `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: `$(document).ready(...)` was the quickest way. Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 6):

use [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) which does not reload the page or leave a trailing `#`:-

```
history.pushState('', '', window.location.pathname);
```

> **pushState()** takes three parameters: a state object, a title (which is currently ignored), and (optionally) a URL.
>
> **URL** — The new history entry's URL is given by this parameter. Note that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to
>   pushState(), but it might attempt to load the URL later, for instance
>   after the user restarts the browser. The new URL does not need to be
>   absolute; if it's relative, it's resolved relative to the current URL.
>   The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise,
>   pushState() will throw an exception. This parameter is optional; if it
>   isn't specified, it's set to the document's current URL.
>
> In a sense, calling pushState() is similar to setting window.location
>   = "#foo", in that both will also create and activate another history entry associated with the current document. But pushState() has a few
>   advantages:
>
> The new URL can be any URL in the same origin as the current URL. In
>   contrast, setting window.location keeps you at the same document only
>   if you modify only the hash.

Comment: I like that this solution removes the trailing `#`. Do you know anything about this being less compatible due to the backwards compatibility that @casraf mentioned.

Comment: the browser compatibility is on the bottom of the link. All new browsers should be good.

Comment: I totally missed the link in your post. Thanks.

Comment: pushState seems to be -very- new. In Firefox, it started with the current major version, 61.

Comment: @BenG this is exactly what i was looking for with also removing the trailing `#` as @Matthew Backman pointed it out. thanks ;D

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.hash = '';//remove hash text
window.location.href.replace('#', '');//remove hash
history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);//replace state
```

Comment: Remove hash successfully but cant remove # from url..

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but to add to BenG's answer, those who don't want their visitors to have an additional step in their History should use `history.`**`replace`**`State(null, null, window.location.pathname)`.

If you use `pushState`, your visitor will hit back and be taken to the state/hash that you removed from the URL, which can lead to lower overall visitor satisfaction.

EDIT: Also, per the OP's use case, I would make sure you bind any `popstate` or `hashchange` functions *after* you've modified the History object (such as any animated `scrollTo`'s or whatnot).